# Why can't I do this in asp.net webforms?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have one `<asp:Image ID="imgBanner1" runat="server"/>` control in my aspx page, then in code behind I have this test code:

```
Image img = new Image();
img.ImageUrl = "~/img/home/home1.jpg";
//...

imgBanner1 = img;  //<--
```

then when I refresh the page, the `src` value of the `<img>` is blank and the picture doesn't appear. I tried to put the snippet in Page_Load, Page_Init, Page_PreInit events but still doesn't work. How can I solve this? I need to asign some custom controls of other clases in my pages... thanks for your answers!.

Edit: **It works if I do this:**

```
imgBanner1.ImageUrl = img.ImageUrl;
//...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to add a control dynamically into a page then add placeholder (or container - Panel etc) control on it and write following code in page_init/page_load. For more info read MSDN article - [How to: Add Controls to an ASP.NET Web Page Programmatically?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyt0fzt1.aspx)

```
Image img = new Image();
img.ImageUrl = "~/img/home/home1.jpg";
PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(img);
```

`ImageUrl` is a string property and you have to set string image url.

Comment: +1 Though I'm pretty sure this should be in `Page_Init` to avoid ViewState issues.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to instantiate a new Image yourself. This code is generated automatically as a protected field in the page.designer.cs code-behind/beside file. All you need to do is have:

```
imgBanner1.ImageUrl = "~/img/home/home1.jpg";
```

in `Page_Load` and all will be well.

Comment: yes I know that, but I create another `Image` control in other class, and one method returns that object, for example one class `PageImage : System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image` with added properties.

Comment: Now you say that, and edit your question. Sigh. Well, listen to AVD above - add the control dynamically to a placeholder control in Page_Init.

Comment: No, I put that since the beginning "I need to asign some custom controls of other clases in my pages" I guess you can check the edit history. btw thanks for your answer.. +1 :)